# Xcode 8 - changes to where Core Data/Sqlite Database are saved?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, core-data, persistence

**Xcode** has always saved the **Core Data/Sqlite** database files of any given App in that App's `Documents` folder - by default. But has that just gotten changed in **Xcode 8**?

I just created a new Core Data App (in **Xcode 8.1**) and after running the App I couldn't find the usual three `sqlite` files in the app's `Documents` folder. Instead, and after much digging around, I discovered those sqlite files in the App's `Application Support` folder, which is located inside that app's `Library` folder.

Is this a bug? Or is this the new thing now?

I thought that if we wanted to persist data in an iOS App, the data ***had*** to be written into the `Documents` folder -  and that calling  `saveContext()` did just that, automatically.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: My file is getting saved to the documents folder as follows:  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D889755E-CAE8-4BC8-8E6A-84AB84DD3A5D/Documents/LocalStore.sqlite

Comment: OK - and you're using Xcode 8.1? And simply doing a straight up `managedObjectContext?.save()` without any additional set-up before that?

Comment: I'm in the 8.2 Beta 2, but still using the old do it yourself set up of the CoreData stack - maybe the new set up does it differently?